# Как узнать IP-адреса подключенные к локальной сети?

Tags: java, сеть, ip

Как узнать IP-адреса подключенные к локальной сети?

Answer (score 3):

Если требуется именно на java, то ответ есть здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345857/how-to-get-a-list-of-ip-connected-in-same-network-subnet-using-java.

Примерно так:

```
public static void checkHosts(String subnet) throws IOException {   
    int timeout = 100;
    for (int i = 1; i < 255; i++) {
        String host = subnet + "." + i;
        if (InetAddress.getByName(host).isReachable(timeout)) {
            System.out.println(host + " is reachable");
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] arguments) throws IOException {
    checkHosts("192.168.1");
}
```